# Splitting other_tags from .osm file

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, other-tags

I am converting an .osm file to a .shp file with OGR2OGR:

```
ogr2ogr.exe --config OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING NO -skipfailures -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.osm
```

In `osmconf.ini` the other_tags is set to "yes" (`other_tags=yes`).

This creates an attribute `other_tags` which consists of a huge block of text, containing a lot of different tags.

Is it possible to somehow tell the OGR2OGR to split the `other_tags` into all of those tags it contains?

I searched, and found out that both in ArcGIS and QGIS there are options on how this can be done. but I am interested in doing it from OGR2OGR only.

Comment: `Is it possible to somehow tell the OGR2OGR to split the other_tags into all of those tags it contains?` can you clarify what you mean here, do you mean if you don't know in advance what the keys are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**

Long answer:

It is necessary to know the possible keys within a .osm file **before** creating the GIS file of any format. So you have to scan the whole file twice: once for the keys, and once for the values.

This is basically the way that the QGIS [QuickOSM plugin](https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM) works. Since it is open-source, you can look into that and build your own importer. Preferably in Python to avoid porting code from one programming language to another.

Comment: Hi @AndreJ . I apologize for not seeing your reply back when you posted it.
Thank you for it, and once again sorry for missing it.

Answer (score 6):

**In QGIS 3.6**, it is now possible to explode the "other_tags" HStore field.
The algorithm will create one field for each unique key.

[image: explode hstore field algorithm]

Comment: Is QGIS 3.6 already released?

Comment: In February 2019, but answers on SE are there for ever. And people might run QGIS dev